# mapping cname to my custom domain name results in posts with cname only

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I have a custom domain yourtechchick.com hosted with openshift. I have mapped Cname your-techchick.rhcloud.com to http://www.yourtechchick.com and it seems to work. But, When I click on posts, It leads to url with your-techchick.rhcloud.com/post-name . I want it to be yourtechchick.com/post-name. How do I fix this?

My permalink shows your-techchick.rhcloud.com option only. Is it possible to fix this with wordpress url and site url thing?

Also, I would like to know in detail the difference between wordpress url and site url.

I somewhere read this is where I need to change, if yes, which amongst these needs to be changed to http://www.yourtechchick.com from http://your-techchick.rhcloud.com.

and In case I mess up these settings, which file will I need to reupload through ftp client in wordpress directory?

Comment: Have you tried adding the proper aliases to your app in your openshift control page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to log into your wordpress admin, and change the home and siteurl options to be your custom domain, instead of the app-domain.rhcloud.com that you originally set it up with.  Here is some official wordpress documentation for reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL